# How can I specify defaultValueSql for all primary keys in entity framework core and npgsql

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have my own sequence generating function in PostgreSql, `next_id()` below, that I would like to use as default value for all primary keys with Entity Framework Core. Is there any way to achieve this?

I am trying to avoid the following situation where I have to specify it for all entities.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Don't want to repeat this command for every entity!
        builder.Entity<Vote>()
        .Property(v => v.VoteId)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("next_id()");

        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
foreach (var type in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    var primaryKey = type.FindPrimaryKey();
    if (primaryKey.Properties.Count == 1 && primaryKey.Properties[0].ClrType == typeof(int))
        primaryKey.Properties[0].Relational().DefaultValueSql = "next_id()";
}
```

Depending on your needs, you might remove `ClrType == typeof(int)` criteria or add another (like `primaryKey.Properties[0].ClrType == typeof(long)` etc.)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!